# JAVA: Create boolean variable or put argument within If statement?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, boolean, statements

I've been running through a lot of code reviews and keep running into a situation where I see conflicting coding standards regarding boolean variables and if statements.

Here is an example of one method(1):

```
boolean isXTrue = getBooleanValue(DataSetX);

if (isXTrue) {
//do code
}
```

Here is an example of the other method(2):

```
if (getBooleanValue(DataSetX)) {
//do code
}
```

Both do the same thing and function just fine. In some cases, method 1 is a lot more readable since the boolean variable can be named something meaningful, while method 2 saves more lines and unnecessary boolean variable creations.

Maybe I am reading too deep into a simple coding standard, but I'm rather curious that if we use method 1 more often, we could have unnecessary booleans being made.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I wanted to get some opinions anyway :)

Comment: What you said, nothing more nothing less, both are almost the same (except the byte on the stack because of the variable), one could be more readable (depends, if (this.hasBeenAnswered()) is quite readable without a variable name) the other is for sure shorter.

Comment: I always prefer the second option if possible. It can be as readable as a variable if you choose a proper name for the method.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was assuming, but wanted some more opinions on (since I'm not very fluent on the backside memory allocation as others). It seems very situational, if you only need the boolean argument once, just through the method call in the if statement. If you need it multiple times throughout a class, create a variable for it. Thanks for the input!

Comment: We are told explicitly for Boolean methods to just return an argument when we can. So instead of if (isXTrue) {return true;} we do return getBooleanValue(DataSetX);

Comment: My, highly personal, rule of thumb is: If the variable isn't going to be used anywhere else then there's no reason for it to exist. This is of course not limited to neither booleans nor if-statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the compiler will optimize both cases so that either way is identical at run time. Of course, that depends on code outside the context that you've provided.

As for the question at large: it's something that you and your coworkers or group need to come to a consensus about. If you're looking for a definite answer about which one to choose, I don't think you're going to get anything convincing other than personal preferences of readability vs line count.

Discuss this with the others that maintain your code base and decide on which should be preferred. Clearly explain why. Then move on to more...err...important issues.

As for my preference? I like option 1. To me, it's more readable, the variable name can be something descriptive like `isActive`, which makes the code easier to read. Also, inspecting values during debugging is probably easier as you have a definite variable with which to reference prior to its use later in the chain. Again, that's *my* preference.

Comment: NOOOOO you're WRONGNGG it's OPTION TWOO *froths at mouth* +1, discuss and decide _within your team_

Comment: I agree, this isn't a very important issue. I'm have OCDD (Obsessive Compulsive Developer Disorder) and want everything to be the same, but that won't happen. :) Definitely preference based on this for our team of 20+. If the same argument occurs more than once, just make a variable, otherwise just put the method in there for the one case. Thanks for the input!

Comment: +1 For readability arguments.
The only exception I can see here is using a if(isThisTrue()) kind of method, where the name explains everything already.